# How to add a model on surface of another object?

Tags: mesh, 3d-cursor

I have long shifted to Blender from 3ds Max since about 5 years ago. I am missing one option though, maybe because I haven't researched about it yet and I would like know:

In 3D's Max, you can literally create another primitive on an existing objects surface by making it your grid. Blender's power is 3D Cursor but is it possible get the cursor so precise to a models surface quickly?

I can surely think of few other ways but was wondering if there is an Add-on or a way to speed up the workflow.

Thank you in advance,
Waqas

Comment: Select the face (or vertices) where you want to line up the cursor, and press Shift+S (snap to) and choose **Snap cursor to selected**.

Comment: If you Left click on the surface of the object in Solid interaction mode the cursor will stick to it. This isn't precious align but it's fast. Other than that Snap cursor or snapping during transform can be a way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on snapping in the view header and if you set the origin of your primitive to the bottom of the object, then you can move it about the surface of the main object and have it snap to the faces.[image: snapping]

[Max Puliero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luFz5gzvM9s&t=240s) has a great video showing some cool stuff with this.

Comment: That's indeed great method but to be honest I couldn't make it to work. Shrinkwrap [works like I expect it to](https://imgur.com/a/DHyb5) - snapping only those vertices which were weighted more than 0. Other ones won't neither rotate according to the surface nor move preserving the mesh form regarding those weight painted.

Comment: Center the object to be placed with the origin at the bottom, and turn on all the snapping options. If you want to use Max's method, then you set up weight groups to use as ref for the shrinkwrap modifier.

Comment: I got it working if I enable Snap during Transform. What freezed my brain was that Max has Snap disabled in the video (but snapping options enabled); maybe he presses Ctrl while translating though.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.92 has added this feature.  You can select it from the list of tools on the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the moment i have this solution to make things easy.

- Install a small addon from Masterxeon called
  [Power Snapping Pies](https://github.com/mx1001/power_snapping_pies) named in *Blender > 3D View >  Snapping Pies 2.8*
- You'll have a new <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  pie menu with some cool option (*Snap Cursor to selected* in *Edit Mode*, it can be a face, a vertex, an edge etc..) and then when you'll create the primitive, it will snap to the cursor.